# Conversion from sbt.package.File to java.io.File in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

I'm working on extending Jan Berkel's Android Plugin for SBT.

Right now, I'm wondering, how can I convert `sbt.SettingKey[sbt.package.File]` to `java.io.File`? Is there a way to extract `java.io.File` from `sbt.SettingKey[sbt.package.File]`?

For example:

I have a function:

```
def isUpToDate(input: java.io.File): Boolean
```

which expects `java.io.File` as an argument.

I have a `sbt.SettingKey[sbt.package.File]` (named `myFileKey`) which is mapped to my `File` I need.

How do I call `isUpToDate` with the File mapped to `myFileKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the updated question. I am still assuming you are modifying an existing sbt plugin. And therefore, still you need to introduce a dependency. The value of a setting key only becomes valid *at a particular stage* of the build process. Therefore, to retrieve that value, you need to depend on the setting key.

Please read the section "Task Keys" in the [.sbt Build Definition document](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Basic-Def), to decide whether you need to depend on a plain setting key (static) or on the result of another task (dynamic). It looks to me as if your `isUpToDate` might need to be re-evaluated over and over again. Thus you would need a task.

```
val isUpToDate = TaskKey[Boolean]("isUpToDate", "Description")
val settings = Seq[Setting[_]](
// ....
   isUpToDate <<= fileKey.map(checkUpToDate)
)

private def checkUpToDate(f: File): Boolean = { ... }
```

**Note** that you need `map` here instead of `apply` in order to construct a task from a setting key.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to *compose a dependency* using `<<=`, extracting the file using the `apply` method of the settings key. E.g.

```
yourKey <<= fileKey { file => ... }
```

which is short for

```
yourKey <<= fileKey.apply { file => ... }
```

See the section "Computing a value based on other keys' values" of the [sbt getting-started-guide](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-More-About-Settings).

Also note that `sbt.File` is merely a type alias for `java.io.File`.

---

For example to map some file:

```
val yourKey  = SettingKey[File]("yourKey", "Description")
val settings = Seq[Setting[_]](
  // ....
  yourKey <<= fileKey { f => f / "subdirectory" }
)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: where is ``sbt.package.File`` declared? I quickly searched through the sources (0.13 branch, cbc94f9cb6), but couldn't fine any such declaration.

Comment: It is in the 0.11 branch, a mere type alias (`package object sbt { ... type File = java.io.File ... }`)

Comment: But won't that simply return me another Key[something]? Sorry for dumb questions, I'm new to Scala/SBT

Comment: @Lopina, it will turn it into a `Key[Something]`. But as a side effect you get to use the file to do something.

Comment: Well, yes. It defines the key for your own task that works on the given file. You will need to be more specific about what you try to do with it.

Comment: I want a _File_ contained in SettingKey[File]

Comment: _Where_ do you want it, and _what_ do you want to do _with_ it? You need to clarify that first. You know you can just ask for a key's value in the sbt shell, e.g. `> base-directory` or `> compile:target`

Comment: I want to have in a val, so I can send it to a function that takes java.io.File

Comment: I don't think we understood eachother, I updated my question with an example.